# Icon inside Lightning Badge

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-design-system

I saw on Lightning design system that there is the option to put an icon inside a Badge

> https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/badges/#Badges-with-Icons

How can i actually do it in lightning component? I was looking for a way to put an icon inside this tag:

```
<lightning:badge label="Privacy OK" class="slds-theme_success" />
```

Comment: ootb, for a similar functionality, you might want to take a look at [lightning:pillContainers](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:pillContainer/example)

Comment: So basically, i use pills without the remove option right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar, although not the same component, the [lightning:pill](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:pill/example#lightningcomponentdemo:examplePillIcon) supports adding icons within it:

```
<lightning:pill label="Pill Label">
    <aura:set attribute="media">
        <lightning:icon iconName="standard:account"  alternativeText="Account"/>
    </aura:set>
</lightning:pill>
```

some styling is needed to hide the remove option though:

```
.THIS .slds-pill__remove{
    display:none;
}
```

Otherwise, you will have to tweak the [SLDS Badge Blueprint](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/badges/) - similar to what @codeyinthecloud posted.

Comment: +1 from me. I like this idea better!

Comment: Good answer!! but the CSS may is like that ---->

.THIS .slds-pill__remove {
    display: none !important;
}

Comment: !important is never a good idea (bad practice) you just need to get the selector right, the above one i posted worked properly, not sure where you are applying the css rule

Comment: Right! but your way just hide it, and you can still see it when u go hover with the mouse.

Comment: i retested using .slds-pill__remove without !important, and it works

Answer (score 0):

As svg are not yet supported you can wrap a lightning:icon with the slds styling. You will have to fine tune the styling a little bit.

```
<span class="slds-badge slds-badge_lightest">
    <span class="slds-icon_container slds-icon-utility-world slds-m-right_xx-small" title="Description of icon when needed">
        <span class="slds-icon slds-icon_xx-small slds-icon-text-default">
            <lightning:icon iconName="utility:world" size="small" />
        </span>
    </span>Icon on the left</span>
```

Comment: =P id say more than a little bit considering the minimum size supported by the lightning icon, and seting a min-width to it will screw up the dimensions and so on, but do-able .

Comment: @glls I agree. The idea here is to show an alternative to svg hosting the icon on a badge.

Comment: Dear downvoter would love to understand the reason for downvote!